# How to move the files from Amazon s3 to sftp using shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-s3, sftp, putty

We have a requirement to automate the process of moving the CSV files from Amazon s3 to sftp server using shell scripts(BASH). Can we achieve this requirement using shell scripting? If yes, can someone help me in sharing the sample code?

Comment: Side-note: FTP/SFTP is a very old-fashioned technology that is best avoided. It has poor scalability and redundancy. If at all possible, have them use S3 directly rather than relying on FTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An SFTP server simply makes local files accessible via the SFTP protocol. Therefore, all you need to do is to copy the files from Amazon S3 to the local disk.

This can be done via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 cp` command or, better yet, `aws s3 sync`. This can be called from shell scripts.